# Rename 'figurename' and 'tablename' with japanese characters

Tags: pdftex, captions, japanese

I would like to display the figure and table labels of captions with japanese characters. One of the main restrictions on the solution to this problem is that I would like to compile the latex code using pdfLatex.

My code looks like the following:

```
% PREAMBLE
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt, pagesize, parskip=half-, numbers=noendperiod,
captions=nooneline ]{scrartcl}
% more packages
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[whole]{bxcjkjatype}
\usepackage[justification=centering,tablename={テーブル},figurename={図}]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{モデルの概要表示}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As specified in the preamble, tablename and figurename have been renamed in the preamble. This solution works when I use new labels that have latin characters. However, if I use japanese characters I get the following error

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.8     \usepackage
                   {graphicx}
?
```

Comment: Please instead provide the error message that this explicit MWE produces instead of referring to something the rest of us does not have access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing options to `caption` in `\usepackage` is fragile; use `\captionsetup`.

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt,
  pagesize,
  parskip=half-,
  numbers=noendperiod,
  captions=nooneline,
]{scrartcl}
% more packages
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[whole]{bxcjkjatype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup{
  justification=centering,
  tablename=テーブル,
  figurename=図,
}

% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{モデルの概要表示}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
Table
\caption{モデルの概要表示}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: we really should fix that:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle On the other hand, I somewhat prefer the “setup” approach to long lists of options to the package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh yes, please, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, just to learn, in my case I change the names of the content structures using the macros `\renewcommand\estructurename{New structure name}`, in the case of the scrartcl class, it only allows me to change the following structures, the example lacks of meaning because I copy text in Japanese from wherever I found, but try with images and tables and it works; for the numbering it is something to investigate.

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{コンテンツインデックス} 
\renewcommand\figurename{図} 
\renewcommand\tablename{テーブル} 
\renewcommand\partname{パーティー} 
\renewcommand\abstractname{要約}
```

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% PROCESSOR ARARA V3.0
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% PREAMBLE
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt, pagesize, parskip=half-, numbers=noendperiod,
captions=nooneline ]{scrartcl}
% more packages
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[whole]{bxcjkjatype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\contentsname{コンテンツインデックス} 
\renewcommand\figurename{図} 
\renewcommand\tablename{テーブル} 
\renewcommand\partname{パーティー} 
\renewcommand\abstractname{要約}
% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    \part{日本語で書かないでください}
    私は日本語を知らないが、日本語のテキストxDでこれを記入しなければならない 位置することに由来するのではないかとされる[3]。近代の二つの憲法の表題は、「日本国憲法」および「大日本帝国憲法」であるが、国号を「日本国」または「日本」と直接かつ明確に規定した法令は存在しない。[疑問点 – ノート]ただし、日本工業規格 (Japanese Industrial Standard) では日本国、英語表記をJapanと規定。更に、国際規格 (ISO) では3文字略号をJPN、2文字略号をJPと規定している。また、日本国外務省から発給される旅券の表紙には「日本国」の表記と十六一重表菊[4] を提示している。法令で日本を指し示す表記には統一されておらず日本、日本国、本邦、わが国、などが混在している。
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
        \caption{モデルの概要表示}
    \end{figure}

    室町時代の謡曲・狂言は、中国人に「ニッポン」と読ませ、日本人に「ニホン」と読ませている。安土桃山時代にポルトガル人が編纂した『日葡辞書』や『日本小文典』等には、「ニッポン」「ニホン」「ジッポン」の読みが見られ、その用例から判断すると、改まった場面・強調したい場合に「ニッポン」が使われ、日常の場面で「ニホン」が使われていた[7]。このことから小池清治は、中世の日本人が中国語的な語感のある「ジッポン」を使用したのは、中国人・西洋人など対外的な場面に限定されていて、日常だと「ニッポン」「ニホン」が用いられていたのでは、と推測している[8]。なお、現在に伝わっていない「ジッポン」音については、その他の言語も参照。

    近代以降も「ニッポン」「ニホン」両方使用される中、1934年には文部省臨時国語調査会が「にっぽん」に統一して外国語表記もJapanを廃してNipponを使用するという案を示したこともあったが、不完全に終わった。同年、日本放送協会（NHK）は「放送上、国号としては『にっぽん』を第一の読み方とし、『にほん』を第二の読み方とする」旨の決定をした[9]。

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
            日本放送協会             & P & W & D & L & F  & A & Pts \\
            \hline
            国号としては & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 5 & 12  \\
            臨時国            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 & 9 &  9  \\
            にっぽん          & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & 8 &  7  \\
            読み方   & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & 8 &  7  \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{旨の決定をし}
    \end{table}

\part{日本語で書かないでください}
私は日本語を知らないが、日本語のテキストxDでこれを記入しなければならない 位置することに由来するのではないかとされる[3]。近代の二つの憲法の表題は、「日本国憲法」および「大日本帝国憲法」であるが、国号を「日本国」または「日本」と直接かつ明確に規定した法令は存在しない 近代の二つの憲法の表題は、「日本国憲法」および「大日本帝国憲法」であるが、国号を「日本国」または「日本」と直接かつ明確に規定した法令は存在しな 近代の二つの憲法の表題は、「日本国憲法」および「大日本帝国憲法」であるが、国号を「日本国」または「日本」と直接かつ明確に規定した法令は存在しな\\

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
        日本放送協会             & P & W & D & L & F  & A & Pts \\
        \hline
        国号としては & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 5 & 12  \\
        臨時国            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 & 9 &  9  \\
        にっぽん          & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & 8 &  7  \\
        読み方   & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & 8 &  7  \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{旨の決定をし}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```